Applying to national lab post-docs (LANL, SNL, LLNL) - Letters of Reference
I am based in the US and my question pertains to cultural norms here. I finished my Physics PhD in 2023 and have been seriously applying to post-docs since the beginning of 2024. I took a year off to give birth to my first child and only applied to industry positions during that time. For personal reasons, I believe it would be best to pursue a postdoc at a national lab while I am eligible to do so; however, I am confused by applications that require letters of reference to be submitted along with the application or emailed separately.

Should I request "standing" letters from my references for all national lab positions?
My references are: my PhD advisor, a professor who knows my leadership skills well, and a fellow grad student who is now a postdoc. Is it better to have a professor for the third reference rather than a peer? I could ask my undergraduate research advisor.

Thank you for any advice!

At my lab (SNL) we ask for references which will be contacted directly (usually by phone) if we are considering hiring you. No letters need to be submitted.

Thank you! I agree that SNL positions have not asked for letters upfront but some positions at LANL do. I was wondering how to handle this, do I ask for a new letter per position or ask for a general letter to keep on hand for such applications?

Sorry to say I can’t help you with the other labs - never applied or worked at them.
